# how to access element whose id is variable

Tags: javascript

I need to access elements in html file using javascript, their names are like `arr_1`, `arr_2`, `arr_3`, I wish to use a loop to dynamically create the id then to access them like below:

```
for(var i=0; i< 10; i++) {
  var id = "arr_" + i;

  $document.getElementById('id')....

}
```

But it doesn't work. I remember there is an function to allow me do that, anyone know what that is?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need the dollar sign preceding `document`, and  you should pass your `id` variable to the `getElementById` function, not a string containing `'id'`:

```
for(var i=0; i< 10; i++) {
  var id = "arr_" + i;
  var element = document.getElementById(id);
  // work with element
}
```

You might also want to check if `getElementById` actually found your element before manipulating it, to avoid run-time errors:

```
if (element) {
  element.style.color = '#ff0000';
}
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning the difference between a string literal and a variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  var obj = document.getElementById("arr_" + i);
  obj.style.border = "1px solid red";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

change

```
$document.getElementById('id')
```

to

```
$document.getElementById(id)
```

Comment: It was in his original code -- I was fixing his syntax. He passed a literal string, when he meant to pass the variable `id`. $document is a valid identifier in JS and I didn't look beyond that -- though I agree it's probably a mistake. CMS's answer expressed this more clearly.

Answer (score -1):

Since this question was published and answered quite correctly several times by using `document.getElementById(id)`, another contender has entered the fray, [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which takes any valid CSS selector and returns the first matched element.

Note that because `querySelector` takes a CSS selector, selecting an ID requires prefixing the ID with `#`.

```
for(var i=0; i< 10; i++) {
  // Added the # here in the id variable.
  var id = "#arr_" + i;
  // assuming $document is a reference to window.document in the browser...
  var element = $document.querySelector(id);
  if (element) {
    // do something with element
  }
}
```

[`getElementById` is typically faster than `querySelector`](https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/8274/0/my-getelementbyid-vs-queryselector-benchmark) (in some browsers, twice as fast), which makes sense, since it doesn't have to invoke the CSS subsystem to find the element.

However, the option exists, and Stack Overflow is nothing if not thorough when answering questions.